# $watch on directive link function does not read updated value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

So i've been going around this one the whole morning. And after going through the docs and a lot of stack overflow questions I decided to throw the towel.

Scenario is, I have a directive where on the `link` function i'm watching a property off the controller. This property has the correct value when the `link`function runs but the `$watch` does not detect the changes that are being made on the controller.

Here's the controller:

```
angular
.module('ec.search')
.controller('MapController', function MapController($scope, $rootScope) {
  'use strict';

  var mapCtrl = this,
    google = window.google;

  mapCtrl.activeMerchantCardId = "something";

  mapCtrl.showMerchantLocations = function (locations) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        marker,
        i,
        len;

    for (i = 0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: $scope.map,
        merchant: i
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleMarkerClick);
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
    }
    $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  function handleMarkerClick() {
    var marker = this;
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      mapCtrl.activeMerchantCardId = marker.merchant;
    });
  }
});
```

The directive:

```
angular
.module('ec.search')
.directive('ecMapMerchantCard', function MapMerchantCardDirective() {
'use strict';

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: 'MapController',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    var el = element[0],
        merchantCard;

    scope.$watch(function() {
      return controller.activeMerchantCardId;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      console.log(oldValue);
    }, true);
  }
};  });
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="listing-default-map-wrapper" data-ec-map-sticky>
  <div class="listing-default-map-container"
       data-ec-map
       data-initial-locations='{{ json_encode($merchantLocations, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT) }}'>
  </div>
  <div data-ec-map-merchant-card></div>
</div>
```

So on an initial run, i see the "something" being printed on the console. But if I click around on the markers, that triggers the `handleMarkerClick` function that updated the property value, the `$watch`does not read the update value, it's still "something".

Now probably this is not the most angular way to do this, but i've tried different solutions around stack overflow and none of them seem to work. I do not understand why the directive does not get the new value.

thanks in advances for any input

Comment: Do you have any plukr/fiddle for this?

Comment: I'll try to create one

Comment: I don't think any binding between the parent scope/controller happens when it is accessed through `controller.activeMerchantCardId`. You most likely need to bind using **Isolate Scope One Way String Binding** or **Isolate Scope Two Way Object Binding** see #5 and #6 [here](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750)

Comment: Have you considered using `$broadcast` instead of `$watch` ?